# How to display integers from array into textbox

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I've got a text box called txtbox, and have numbers in an array called number, I need to display the numbers in this array into the textbox in an event procedure (the user will click on Next and i have to show the next number in the number array), I'm fairly new to vb, what i have so far is.

```
Dim number() As Integer

 Dim i As Integer

  For i = 0 to number.Length -1

   Me.txtbox.Text = number(i)

Next
```

Comment: your question says `I need to display the numbers in this array in the textbox` but in your code you ware assigning the textbox value to the arrat as `number(i) = Me.txtbox.Text`

Comment: @NeethuSoman i need to display the numbers in the array INTO the textbox, is that clear enough? maybe Me.txtbox.Text = number(i) is more clear enough?

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that your question is not how to correctly initialize the array but how to access it to show the numbers in the TextBox. You can use `String.Join`, for example:

```
txtbox.Text = String.Join(",", number) ' will concatenate the numbers with comma as delimiter
```

If you only want to show one number you have to know which index of the array you want to access:

```
txtbox.Text = numbers(0).ToString()  ' first
txtbox.Text = numbers(numbers.Length - 1).ToString()  ' last
```

or via LINQ extension:

```
txtbox.Text = numbers.First().ToString()
txtbox.Text = numbers.Last().ToString()
```

If you want to navigate from the current to the next you have to store the current index in a field of your class, then you can increase/decrease that in the event-handler.

Answer (score 1):

To make it simple and use your code:

```
Me.txtbox.Clear()

For i = 0 to number.Length -1

   Me.txtbox.Text &= " " & number(i)

Next 

Me.txtbox.Text = Me.txtbox.Text.Trim
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest a scenario in this in each click of button you will get numbers from the array in sequential order; consider the following code

```
Dim clicCount As Integer = 0 ' <--- be the index of items in the array increment in each click
Dim a(4) As Integer '<---- Array declaration
a = {1, 2, 3, 4} '<---- array initialization
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If clicCount <= a.Length - 1 Then
        TextBox2.Text = a(clicCount)
        clicCount += 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: that's workable, but a bit too complicating and a bit too much work for a noob such as myself, how about looping through all the values in the array and just displaying them in the textbox?